# Using foreach loop for generating sets of coordinates for const plot mark mid

Tags: pgfplots

Refering to page 79 of PGFPLOTS manual version 1.18.1, I see that a set of coordinates are required to plot the following graph:

[image: output1]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ [
const plot mark mid,
] coordinates {
(0,0.1) (0.1,0.15) (0.2,0.5) (0.3,0.62)
(0.4,0.56) (0.5,0.58) (0.6,0.65) (0.7,0.6)
(0.8,0.58) (0.9,0.55) (1,0.52)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, manually making those coordinates is very tedious especially when you have 10+ coordinates. So I would like to use `foreach` loop to define x- and y- coordinates respectively.

The problem is that when I try to use forloop in `coordinates` set, the compilation seems to take forever.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ [
const plot mark mid,
] coordinates {
\foreach \i in {1,2,3} (\i,\i+2)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

On the other hand if I do `forloop` outside the `addplot`, I don't get the desired result:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
\addplot+ [
const plot mark mid,
] coordinates {
(\i,\i+2)
};}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I `\expanded` and `\global`ly collected the `\foreach` results into a token list `\mycoords`.  I then used that in the `\addplot`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newtoks\mycoords
\begin{document}
\mycoords{}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3} {\global\mycoords\expandafter{%
  \expanded{\the\mycoords(\i,\i+2)}} }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ [
const plot mark mid,
] coordinates{\the\mycoords};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do I calculate coordinates like (\i,log10(\i+2))

Comment: ok so I had to use this way instead `(\i,{log10(\i+2)})`.